# flutter pub get specify version

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec, flutter-upgrade

Unexpectedly some of my packages from `pubspec.yaml` was updated, so my program can not be compiled due to errors inside libraries. I do not have any Error in VSC console, but when I try compile it, console return a lot of problems, for example:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1376:31: Error: Expected ',' before this.
                    ErrorSummary(`'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.'),
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1376:29: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                    ErrorSummary(`'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.'),
```

I do not change nothing, but I see that I have a lot of changes inside pubspec.lock, here is git diff:

```
@@ -7,14 +7,14 @@ packages:
      name: archive
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.2.2"
    version: "3.3.0"
  args:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: args
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.0"
    version: "2.3.1"
  async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -63,21 +63,21 @@ packages:
      name: crypto
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.1"
    version: "3.0.2"
  csslib:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: csslib
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.17.1"
    version: "0.17.2"
  cupertino_icons:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: cupertino_icons
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.4"
    version: "1.0.5"
  fake_async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ packages:
      name: ffi
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.2"
    version: "1.2.1"
  file:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -110,7 +110,7 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_form_builder
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.1.1"
    version: "7.3.1"
  flutter_js:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -136,14 +136,14 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_native_splash
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.1"
    version: "2.1.6"
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.6"
  flutter_secure_storage:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -202,28 +202,28 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_widget_from_html_core
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.8.5+1"
    version: "0.8.5+3"
  form_builder_validators:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: form_builder_validators
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.6.1"
    version: "7.9.0"
  fwfh_text_style:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: fwfh_text_style
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.7.3+1"
    version: "2.7.3+2"
  get:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: get
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.6.1"
    version: "4.6.5"
  get_storage:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -251,7 +251,7 @@ packages:
      name: http_parser
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
    version: "4.0.1"
  image:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -294,6 +294,13 @@ packages:
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.3.1"
  lint:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: lint
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.8.2"
  lints:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -391,49 +398,49 @@ packages:
      name: path_provider
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.9"
    version: "2.0.11"
  path_provider_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_android
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.12"
    version: "2.0.14"
  path_provider_ios:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_ios
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.8"
    version: "2.0.9"
  path_provider_linux:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_linux
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.5"
    version: "2.1.7"
  path_provider_macos:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_macos
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.6"
  path_provider_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.3"
    version: "2.0.4"
  path_provider_windows:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_windows
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.7"
  petitparser:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -592,7 +599,7 @@ packages:
      name: win32
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.4.1"
    version: "2.5.2"
  xdg_directories:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -613,7 +620,7 @@ packages:
      name: yaml
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.0"
    version: "3.1.1"
  yaon:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -623,4 +630,4 @@ packages:
    version: "1.0.0+1"
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.8.0"
  flutter: ">=2.8.1"
```

I try run `flutter pub downgrade`, but after this I receive a lot of libraries with version lower than before (in `pubspec.lock`), and console return various similar errors.
How I can rollback to previous version of libraries, or how to safety upgrade all?

Comment: Try deleting pubspec.lock & running flutter pub get command